# Performance of running Azure Functions on AKS Virtual Nodes

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-aks, azure-container-instances

I have followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-kubernetes-keda) to set up an Azure Functions instance in a Kubernetes cluster running on a Virtual Node. Everything is working well except for the performance of virtual node creation. In all cases, it is taking the container 60-70 seconds to enter the running state.

My function has an HTTP trigger. When I use Postman to make a request, the container quickly enters the "Creating" state. After a few seconds, it transitions to the "Waiting" state, where it remains for 50-60 seconds. Finally, the container enters the "Running" state.

Is there anything that I can do to improve the performance of this operation?